# How to create an object cart in Prestashop 1.6

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have problem with create a cart object in Prestashop 1.6. I have an error:

```
2019/11/02 - 22:02:40: Property Cart->id_currency is empty at line 917 in file classes/ObjectModel.php
```

In debug mode I dosen't see a id of cart object and this is the problem in my opinion. This is my code:

```
if($id_product && $checkQty >= $quantity)
    {
        if (!$this->context->cart->id)
        {
            $this->context->cart->add();
            $cart = new Cart();
            if ($this->context->cart->id)
                $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int)$this->context->cart->id;
        }else
        {
            $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
        }  

        $cart->updateQty(
            $quantity, 
            $id_product, 
            $id_product_attribute = null, 
            $id_customization = false,
            $operator = 'up', 
            $id_address_delivery = 0, 
            $shop = null, 
            $auto_add_cart_rule = true
            );

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'confirmation' => '1'
        ));        
    }
```

Of course when I have $cart->id the updateQty works great. Thanks for any help.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the id of the currency.

with that code, you assign in your cart the  currency from the one defined in the context :

```
$cart->id_currency = $context->cookie->id_currency;
```

so in your code it must look like this :

```
if($id_product && $checkQty >= $quantity)
    {
        if (!$this->context->cart->id)
        {
            $this->context->cart->add();
            $cart = new Cart();
            if ($this->context->cart->id)
                $this->context->cookie->id_cart = (int)$this->context->cart->id;
        }else
        {
            $cart = new Cart($this->context->cookie->id_cart);
        }  

        $cart->id_currency = $this->context->cookie->id_currency;

        $cart->updateQty(
            $quantity, 
            $id_product, 
            $id_product_attribute = null, 
            $id_customization = false,
            $operator = 'up', 
            $id_address_delivery = 0, 
            $shop = null, 
            $auto_add_cart_rule = true
            );

        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
            'confirmation' => '1'
        ));        
    }
```